# jquery autocomplete filter second one based on first value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have 2 autocomplete jquery function. I'd like to show in the second only the value based on the one choosen on the first text filed. I do not want to change the original aVal array, because if someone change the first txt value, the second one has to adjust on it.

Here is the code and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCuas/174/):

```
$(function() {
    var shared;

    var aVal = [{label: "odd", value: "1"}, 
                { label: "even", value: "2"}
               ];
    var bVal = [{ label: "one", value: "1"}, 
                { label: "two", value: "2"},
                { label: "three", value: "1"}, 
                { label: "four", value: "2"}
               ];

            $( "#input_txt" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: aVal,
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#input_txt" ).val( ui.item.label );
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#input_txt" ).val( ui.item.label );
                    $( "#input_val" ).val( ui.item.value );
                    shared =  ui.item.value;
                    return false;
                }
            })

            $( "#second_input_txt" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: bVal,
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    if(ui.item.value == shared){
                        $( "#second_input_txt" ).val( ui.item.label );
                    }                        
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#second_input_txt" ).val( ui.item.label );
                    $( "#second_input_val" ).val( ui.item.value );
                    return false;
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: Like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/7at0moab/1/

Comment: ok, now it works, there was anly a little error od the source function. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right solution (there was only a little error on source function - Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913845/ovaherenow)

```
$(function() {
    var share=-1;

    var aVal = [{ 
                    label: "odd",
                    value: "1"
                }, 
            { 
                label: "even",
                value: "2"
            }
        ];
var bVal = [{ 
                label: "one",
                value: "1"
            }, 
            { 
                label: "two",
                value: "2"
            },
            { 
                label: "three",
                value: "1"
            }, 
            { 
                label: "four",
                value: "2"
            }
        ];

        $( "#input_txt" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: aVal,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#input_txt" ).val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#input_txt" ).val( ui.item.label );
                $( "#input_val" ).val( ui.item.value );
                share =  ui.item.value;
                //alert(share);
                return false;
            }
        })

        $( "#second_input_txt" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response){
                var bValnew=new Array();
                if(share==-1) return bValnew;

                for(var a=0;a<bVal.length;a++){
                    if(bVal[a].value==share){
                       bValnew.push(bVal[a]);
                    }
                }              
                response(bValnew);
            },
            focus: function( event, ui ) {

                $( "#second_input_txt" ).val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#second_input_txt" ).val( ui.item.label );
                $( "#second_input_val" ).val( ui.item.value );
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
```